# how to block YouTube from ooredoo Huawei mobile wifi

Tags: firefox

Im using a mobile wifi network shared with friends, but it has limited data. I told my friend not to open online videos like YouTube, but he still did so.

How can I block the site?

Comment: IINM "mobile wifi network shared with friends" is a Huawei MiFi device that isn't tethered to anything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[BlockSite](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/blocksite/) is a Firefox extension which automatically blocks websites of your choice. Additionally, this extension will disable all hyperlinks to these websites, by just displaying the link text without the clicking functionality.

#### Features

- Create block lists - Add the websites or pages you want to block in a smart and simple way. Get automatically redirected to safer, more positive sites. Build a more effective work environment for yourself
- Bulk adult sites - All adult sites can now be blocked with a single click.
- Control your browsing - Set up the sites you want to be redirected to. Make sure your internet usage is productive and effective. Block social media sites, adult content or other sites you find disturbing.
- Improve productivity - Right-click anywhere on any website to open the quick access menu. Block sites in seconds to avoid procrastination and stay on target.
- Block by keywords - Block sites and search queries on search engines like Google or Bing, based on specific words. Make sure you choose what to block wisely, so Keyword Block will only stop the sites and pages you're not interested in.
- Keep your kids' internet safe - Activate "Adult related" keyword block to filter out all predefined bad words and profanities.
- Block for specific times -Choose days and intervals in which you want Block site to be active. Set up custom blocks based on your work schedule (for example: 09:00 - 17:00), so you won't procrastinate during the day, when at work or at school.
- Switch between blacklists & whitelists - Create a list of friendly sites, and switch from blocking specific sites to only allowing certain sites to work.

#### Usage

1. In Firefox go to *Tools*, and click *Add-ons*. Click *Get Add-ons* followed by *Browse All Add-ons*.
2. Firefox add-ons website will open. Type *Blocksite* in the search bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Click *Add to Firefox*.
4. Click *Install Now*.
5. Restart Firefox when prompted.
6. Once Firefox is restarted, again go to *Tools*, then *Add-ons*. Select  BlockSite and click *Preferences*. Tick *Blacklist*, *Enable BlockSite messages* and *Enable link removal* buttons.
7. This add-on is password protected. Enter a password after checking *Enable authentication* if you don't want anyone else to make changes in your BlockSite settings.
8. Click the *Add* button. Copy and paste (or type) the URL of the website which you wish to block. Click *OK*.
9. After restarting Firefox, the website will be blocked.